# javascript if else statement updating a var

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, timer

I am making a timer which needs to count down to my next lectures at school. I've made an array with the dates of my coming lectures and a timer which is counting down to the first date in the array.

The problem is this: If the timer has gone below 0, I want it to go to the next date in the array and count down to this date. Now I made an if statement like this:

```
if (seconds < 0 ) {
        firstLecture = i++;
        console.log(i)
    }
```

I can see in my console that i is updating every second but my timer is still going further on the first date. How can I fix this problem? Do I need a loop or something like that?

```
var lectures = ["April 16, 2015 16:25:00", "April 16, 2015 19:25:00", "April 17, 2015 10:10:00", "April 17, 2015 14:20:00"]
var i = 0
var firstLecture = lectures[i];

var date = new Date(firstLecture);
var $display = $('#countdown');
countdown($display, date);
setInterval(function () { countdown($display, date); }, 1000);


function countdown($display, collision) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(now.getHours() + (get_time_zone_offset()+2));
    var seconds = Math.floor((collision.getTime() - now.getTime()) * 0.001);
    var minutes = (Math.floor(seconds/60) % 60); //60 minutes in an hour
    var hours = (Math.floor(seconds/60/60 * 10)/10) % 24; //24 hours in a day
    var days = Math.floor((seconds/60/60/24));
    //var weeks = Math.ceil((days/7) * 100)/100;
    $display
            .html
    (
            '<p>' +
            collision +
            '<br>seconds: ' + seconds +
            '<br>minutes: ' + minutes +
            '<br>hours: ' + hours +
            '<br>days: ' + days +
                //'<br>weeks: ' + weeks +
            '</p>'
    );

    if (seconds < 0 ) {
        firstLecture = i++;
        console.log(i)
    }
}

function get_time_zone_offset() {
    var current_date = new Date();
    var gmt_offset = current_date.getTimezoneOffset( ) / 60;
    return gmt_offset;
}
```

Comment: You need [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

Answer (score 0):

Without going through your whole process, your line:

```
firstLecture = i++;
```

looks like it is supposed to be:

```
firstLecture = lectures[++i];
```

Right now you're setting it to an integer, when I believe you want to set it to the next item in your array.